# Class of words which emphasize meaning of other words

Tags: linguistics

I've read before some article where such linguistic term was introduced, but I forgot it. Can you help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Likely you're looking for *intensifier*, which in English is a category of modifiers that add emphasis or push a gradable property toward its extreme. Thus

> You are **so very** beautiful.

adds emphasis to the estimation of your good looks with two intensifiers. English also has a set of intensive pronouns that add emphasis. These end in *-self*. So if I say

> I **myself** wrote the poem.

you would understand that I am emphasizing my authorship as something out of the ordinary.

Comment: Thanks for response! This word pretty much suit to my search despite the fact that it not actually is (that one starts with letter 'm'). I think this question lacks importance at all and I'll close it.